# Cannot interact with input (role=combobox) using Selenium WebDriver (Firefox)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, css, selenium

I'm studying Selenium WebDriver and testing my skills on a public site. The issue is that I cannot interact with input element with role='combobox' using Selenium WebDriver + Java.
I need to interact (select 2d option) for the first element of calculator ("Калькулятор"-"Тип расчета" - combobox near this text). Firefox shows the code for it:

```
<div class="select2-search">

<label class="select2-offscreen" for="s2id_autogen2_search"></label>
<input id="s2id_autogen2_search" class="select2-input" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="true" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" aria-owns="select2-results-2" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-17"></input>
```

When I try to click or sendkeys for it it writes that element (both selects and selects2) is not visible although it is visible and interactable manually. CSS is not transformed. I found that JS can change property to make the element visible, but I tried - and nothing changed, isDisplayed() shows false and I cannot select 2d item of the combobox.

Here is the code (I have left only main part)):

```java
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://sberbank.ru/ru/person/credits/money/consumer_unsecured");

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            }catch(Exception e)
        {System.out.println("Error in Sleep.");}
        List<WebElement> selects = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".select2-search"));//(".select2-results"));
        List<WebElement> selects2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@class='select2-input']"));
        System.out.println("xpath: "+selects2.size());
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,1000);");
        System.out.println("value:"+selects2.get(0).getAttribute("value"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.display='inline';arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';arguments[0].style.height = '20px';arguments[0].style.width = '80px';",selects2.get(0));
        System.out.println("visible: "+selects2.get(0).isDisplayed());
        System.out.println("enabled: "+selects2.get(0).isEnabled());
        System.out.println("height: "+selects2.get(0).getAttribute("height")+",width: "+selects2.get(0).getAttribute("width"));
        selects2.get(0).click();
        selects2.get(0).sendKeys("По среднемесячному доходу");
```

It writes:
xpath: 7
value:
visible: false
enabled: true
height: 0,width: 0
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

I also tried to trigger keyevent with JQuery but it didn't help:

```java
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("var s=window.document.createElement('script');" +
        "s.src='D:\\Data\\Selenium\\jquery-1.11.3.min.js';" +
        "window.document.head.appendChild(s);");
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].focus();var e = jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 65 });arguments[0].trigger(e);", selects2.get(0));
```

It writes "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguments[0].trigger is not a function"

Please help me to fix my code to be able to set 2d item of this combobox.

Comment: I checked the website and element with html you posted is actually not visible. Could you tell which field on the webpage you are trying to interact with?

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img913/892/z9croh.png I'm trying to select this field. I need 2d option "По среднемесячному доходу". I have no clue why it is not visible although I changed in a code visibility and display option - see code.

Comment: I ivestigated the site and found that this element is included into div with display='none', I modified it and now I can SendKeys to the input, but it looks rather strange and not what it should look like:

Comment: List<WebElement> selects3 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".select2-drop"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.display='inline';arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';arguments[0].style.height = '20px';arguments[0].style.width = '80px';",selects3.get(0));
 selects3.get(0).click();
        selects2.get(0).sendKeys("По среднемесячному доходу");
        selects2.get(0).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

Comment: It writes a text in a box near where I expeted and nothing happens so select option wasn't used.

Comment: It seems that I have to run javascript from the site to make it work, but I don;t know how to know what script and function to run. When I click on the element in FireFox and inspects element clicking triggers function, new element replaces initial and I cannot catch the initial element.

Comment: Please check my answer, and let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working -

```
driver.get('http://sberbank.ru/ru/person/credits/money/consumer_unsecured')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen1"]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="select2-results ps-container"]/li[2]').click()
```

Comment: Great, that works. I searched same element byid, but it failed.
Thank you.

Comment: No problem. I am glad it helped. Please select my answer as successful.